# How many data can be read when poll return POLLIN

Tags: sockets, pool, recv

If there is client/server tcp communication case:

The client Send 1MB message to the server, In the server side we use the poll() and recv() function to read the message from the socket, the sequence may like
Poll -> POLLIN -> recv -> Poll -> POLLIN - recv ............ Poll -> POLLIN - recv

My question is 
If the poll() function tell me the socket status is POLLIN, When I read from the socket FD, the size of data read from the socket is return by the recv api as "ssize_t". How much is "ssize_t", is there some rule or some setting we can control. As we don't want to read only 1 byte with 1024*1024 time for 1MB data because it degrade the system performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POLLIN only signals that **some** data are available for reading. It does not provide any information how much data are available. But you can simply read as much data you want since `recv` will not wait until all data you might want are available but will simply return with what can be read so far.

Comment: So that If we want to read the full message,  we don't know how many  times recv will  be call, even a rough estimation  like 10times, 100times, or 1000 times.

Comment: @hongshuwei: How many times you need to call `recv` depends on the size of the data, the size of the socket buffers, the window of the TCP connection, the amount of bytes you read with a single call etc. There is no estimate possible just based on POLLIN. Also, TCP has no concept of a "message" in the first place but knows only a stream of bytes.